# Apache workers upate

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, ubuntu-12.04

I would like to update 2 ubuntu(newest packages, fixes) servers which are balancer members(Apache) running on esxi as Virtual Machines with internal IP's and running on the internal network. What would be the best workaround to update theme or install new packages, How can achieve this without having internet.

Comment: What do you mean with "update"? Installing the newest fixes? Upgrade to a new Ubuntu release? Something else? Workaround for what problem?

Comment: yes installing newest fixes

Answer (score 2):

Download the packages to a USB stick, or setup your own internal repo. You can't route these outside long enough to get the updates?